# Function run before view load

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I would like to run a function before the view load, I tried on `initWithNibName` but without success.
There is any function that loads before it render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in `loadView`:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [self myImportantMethod];

    [super loadView];
}
```

This ensures your `myImportantMethod` is called before the view controller's view is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried initWithFrame? In my experience *one* of those is called first.

Comment: Since the OP mentions `initWithNibName` this must be about view controllers. The `initWithFrame` method is for `UIView`, not `UIViewController`.

Comment: yeah, that's right. I remember being confused by that at one time.